# How to make roscd go to ~/catkin_ws/devel instead of /opt/ros/kinetic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have sourced the `setup.bash` in the `devel` folder of `catkin_ws` but still the `roscd` command takes to `/opt/ros/kinetic`

On `env | grep ROS`, the output is:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/username/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286880/how-to-make-roscd-go-to-%7E/catkin_ws/devel-instead-of-/opt/ros/kinetic?/) by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2018-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tim Stadtmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/34135/tim-stadtmann/) on 2018-03-28**:
Just to make sure: did you only add the `source /home/username/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` line to your .bashrc, or did you actually source `setup.bash`/open up a new terminal after adding the line?

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2018-03-28**:
I added it to `.bashrc` as well. And then sourced it through terminal also.

**Comment by [hc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27378/hc/) on 2018-03-28**:\

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/username/catkin_ws/src:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, after reading @SimonDahrs's answer, I checked the [source](https://github.com/ros/ros/blob/90759adc4a3ffbeaa1e9036e5fe874e21dfaf6c5/tools/rosbash/rosbash#L144) (sorry, couldn't find it in the docs) out and saw that `roscd` checks two different environment variables: `ROS_WORKSPACE` *and* `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. (Unless I'm missing something, this is basically how it works.) First, `roscd` checks if `ROS_WORKSPACE` is set and `cd`s to that location if it is set and returns. If `ROS_WORKSPACE` isn't set, it checks if `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is set and iterates through each path and the first path that contains a `.catkin` directory  is `cd`ed to. What does this mean?

Each time you `source` a ROS `setup.bash` (or equivalent) the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is changed and to be the workspace that the `setup.bash` file resides in. So, if you want to the default path of `roscd` either set `ROS_WORKSPACE` to your desired path, or source the `setup.bash` file from the workspace that you want to have as the default path.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2020-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without any arguments it goes to the ROS_ROOT by default. There's no way to override that. If you `roscd <PACKAGE_NAME>` for some `<PACKAGE_NAME>` in your workspace it should take you to the package's directory.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mine did the same for a fresh Melodic installation. The thing is that if you try to use `roscd` on the newly instantiated catkin_ws with no packages, then it will go to /opt/ros/melodic. If you add a package to `src/` and build the workspace, then roscd should take you to `~/catkin_ws/devel/` afterwards.

---

Originally posted by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) with karma: 84 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1